# Setting X of camera's viewport causes the black strip to be rendered

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, camera

I’ve run out of ideas, please help me.

That's the situation:

1. Imagine a simple object in the center of screen (it's always so, because camera has an orbit script)
   [image]
2. Then we add a canvas image, 300px width, for example, on the right side of the screen (blue one in the picture). Our cube is not centered anymore.
   [image]
3. For example, we can change X property of camera viewport rect, but we'll get a black strip and if object appears in this zone, it would not be rendered.
   [image]

So, what can I do to offset camera position?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try rendering the cube to a `render texture`, attaching it to a UI image, with `aspect ratio fitter`, and `mask`.

Comment: I've thought about RenderTexture, however I need 4k resolutuin, but my target platform is WebGL. Hello, "OutOfMemory"

Comment: sry, resolution*

Answer (score 0):

The best option I have for now is:

- create basic UI for FullHD resolution and make right panel as wide as black strip is
- if user's screen bigger than 1920px, than change Canvas Scaler mode from Constant pixel size to Scale with screen size

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewport settings and changing the variables. Ive done the same with my split screen game.

Also if you found any other way to solve this, let me know!

Comment: Hello, you need to be more specific with your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).